# How to prevent a prompt from continuing a keydown event?

Tags: javascript, events, prompt, keydown

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", event => {
    const key = event.key;
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.ctrlKey) {
        heightPrompt = prompt("How high do you want to go? Your last height was: " + lastHeight);
        newHeight = parseInt(heightPrompt);
        player.y = newHeight;
    }
});
```

I have a keydown event that triggers when pressing the Ctrl key. A prompt pops up and the user can enter information. The problem is that after the prompt is already closed*, Ctrl is apparently still being counted as pressed. There is another event listener across the entire website listening for Ctrl + m to mute and unmute the sound on the website. And I cannot type anything while I am apparently "holding" Ctrl. I know it's holding Ctrl because if I press m afterwards, the site will mute/unmute.

The prompt seems to change the way the computer interprets my input, since simply clicking Ctrl without the prompt in the code does not cause Ctrl to be "held".

Comment: It's because you use `keydown` event. Everything within the callback function is triggered while keydown is still active. Use `keyup` or `keypress` instead. You probably don't want to use `keydown` anyway. It would always trigger this event, even when the user just tries to mute. It'll become very annoying to them.

Comment: @icecub i actually had Ctrl + another key but i removed some code to make the question smaller/simpler. Thank you though.

Comment: Still doesn't change the reason for your problem though. You're triggering a callback function as soon as the key is down. The key will not be considered up until that function is finished. If you really _must_ rely on `keydown`, you gonna have to create custom booleans that keep track of key states, allowing you to manually control them.